# Automapper projection (EF) with encapsulated child collections

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

I use Automapper to map from EF entities to view models.

I now have this entity

```
public class MenuGroup : IEntity
{
    public int MenuGroupId { get; set; }

    protected ICollection<MenuGroupItem> _menuGroupItems { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MenuGroupItem> MenuGroupItems { get { return _menuGroupItems; } }

    public void AddMenuItem(MenuGroupItem menuGroupItem)
    {
        _menuGroupItems.Add(menuGroupItem);
    }
}
```

That is an encapsulated collection, I followed instructions here to make this work: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/09/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-encapsulated-collections/

So I configure it like so `this.HasMany(x => x.MenuGroupItems).WithRequired(x => x.BelongsTo).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);`

Now the problem I get is when I try to use automapper to map my `MenuGroup` into a viewmodel.

I run this code: `menuGroup = _context.MenuGroups.Project().To<MenuGroupEditModel>().Single(x => x.UniqueUrlFriendlyName == request.UniqueUrlFriendlyName);`

and get this error: `The specified type member 'MenuGroupItems' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

---

Now I can work with the collection, it saves correctly to the database and all is well there it's only when i want to user automapper here that it fails.

If I replace the protected ICollection and public IEnumerable with simply: `public ICollection<MenuGroupItem> MenuGroupItems { get; set; }` it works right away so the problem lies in automapping with my encapsulated collection.

---

**Update:** I also tried this `menuGroup = _context.MenuGroups.Include(x => x.MenuGroupItems).Where(x => x.UniqueUrlFriendlyName == request.UniqueUrlFriendlyName).Project().ToSingleOrDefault<MenuGroupEditModel>();` with no difference other than that it errored in the ToSingleOrDefault instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging I figured out the Config file looking like this

```
    public MenuGroupConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasMany(x => x.MenuGroupAssigments).WithRequired(x => x.BelongTo).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        this.HasMany(x => x.MenuGroupItems).WithRequired(x => x.BelongsTo).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
```

had not been included leading to that error that now makes sense.

---

I can add as a general tip that if you don't use auto-mapper for a query but still use your encapsulated collection remember that you have to call decompile for it to work.

like so

```
        var menuGroupsWithType =
            _context.MenuGroups.Include(x => x.MenuGroupItems).Include(x => x.MenuGroupAssigments).Where(x => x.MenuGroupAssigments.Any(y => y.AssignToAll == selectedStructureType))
                .OrderBy(x => x.Name).Decompile().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Automapper can't modify `MenuGroupItems` because there is no public setter.

Your solution is changing it to this:

```
public IEnumerable<MenuGroupItem> MenuGroupItems { get; set; }

public void AddMenuItem(MenuGroupItem menuGroupItem)
{
    MenuGroupItems.Add(menuGroupItem);
}
```

Comment: Hmm okay but if I do then what happens to my encapsulation of the ICollection. I will have to run some tests. It's not ideal to be forced to need a set. Also, why does it need a set method. I project from this type not to this type.

Comment: If you need an external component to modify it, then it's normal to have a setter

Comment: Yes but I don't need an external component to modify it since I project _from_ this type not to it.

Comment: EF attempts to access it when it builds your model from the database result

Comment: Well yes but EF has a lot of special code to make sure it actually uses the ICollection which has a setter. Automapper however should only need to map from this type not to it.